# MySQL Like multiple values

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like

I have this MySQL query.

I have database fields with this contents

```
sports,shopping,pool,pc,games 
shopping,pool,pc,games 
sports,pub,swimming, pool, pc, games
```

Why does this like query does not work?
I need the fields with either sports or pub or both?

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE interests LIKE ('%sports%', '%pub%')
```

Answer (score 160, accepted):

The `(a,b,c)` list only works with `in`. For `like`, you have to use `or`:

```
WHERE interests LIKE '%sports%' OR interests LIKE '%pub%'
```

Comment: This wouldn't be beneficial in multiple (let's say 5 or more dynamic searchable query), thus, it'd be better to use regexp.

Comment: @ShayanAhmad What do you mean by beneficial? In terms of creating the query or query exection time? Isn't LIKE a lot more otpmized than REGEXP ?

Answer (score 423):

Faster way of doing this:

```
WHERE interests LIKE '%sports%' OR interests LIKE '%pub%'
```

is this:

```
WHERE interests REGEXP 'sports|pub'
```

Found this solution here: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,392332,392950#msg-392950

More about REGEXP here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-regexps.htm

Comment: if you are passing in an unknown amount of keywords as a string (a|b|c...), the regexp is the only way to go if you want to do LIKE, is it?

Comment: Do you know if this can be done with a subquery? Let's say I have a column of words I need to search for, how can I replace 'sports|pub' with a subquery?

Comment: Hey, could you please tell me the REGEXP for LIKE instead of %LIKE%, I am trying to fetch exact strings...

Comment: is it possible to use something like this format? WHERE interests REGEXP 'ex1|ex2|ex3|ex4|ex5|ex6|.... ex100'  ??? what's its limitation?

Comment: To get the regexp value from a column: `(select group_concat(myColumn separator '|') from..)`

Comment: are you sure `REGEXP` is faster of `LIKE` ->  MySQL doesn't use index with REGEXP. This is a primary issue, nice article related -> http://www.dbasquare.com/2012/03/31/mysql-queries-with-regexp/

Comment: Thanks Jazkat. REGEXP one works perfectly & it's more reliable

Comment: Cool, It is indeed faster, for my query 'like' runs forever and results in connection timeout. But this REGEXP returns me result in less than 5 seconds!

Comment: in SQL, REGXP is much lower than LIKE

Comment: REGXP is very slow in execution

Comment: Do you know a way to do that in SQL Server?

Comment: For case sensitive, use BINARY: `WHERE interests REGEXP BINARY 'sports|pub'`

Answer (score 44):

Why not you try REGEXP. Try it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE interests REGEXP 'sports|pub'
```

Comment: Yeah!! I want it the opposite way. So it is `SELECT * FROM table WHERE interests NOT REGEXP 'sports|pub'`  (>‿◠)✌

Comment: How this answer is different from `jazkat` answer submitted 5 years before yours?

Comment: @Vaidas - thank you - was asking myself the same question ... :D

Comment: it's sort and simple (●'◡'●)

Answer (score 35):

You can also use `REGEXP`'s synonym `RLIKE` as well.

For example:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE COLNAME RLIKE 'REGEX1|REGEX2|REGEX3'
```

Comment: Just note for everyone that RLIKE and REGEXP are synonym

Answer (score 16):

Or if you need to match only the beginning of words:

```
WHERE interests LIKE 'sports%' OR interests LIKE 'pub%'
```

you can use the regexp caret matches:

```
WHERE interests REGEXP '^sports|^pub'
```

https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html

Comment: this is not working, i have values like "1, 2,3, 30, 20" . So when I run query WHERE interests REGEXP '3^|2^'  it will not return any data.

Comment: "if you need to match only the beginning of words" it should be:  WHERE interests REGEXP '^(sports|pub)'

Answer (score 11):

Don't forget to use parenthesis if you use this function after an `AND` parameter

Like this:

```
WHERE id=123 and(interests LIKE '%sports%' OR interests LIKE '%pub%')
```

Answer (score 8):

Your query should be `` SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE find_in_set(interests, "sports,pub")>0 ``

What I understand is that you store the interests in one field of your table, which is a misconception. You should definitively have an "interest" table.

Comment: I think it should be `SELECT * FROM table WHERE find_in_set(interests, 'sports,pub')`, but this technique is likely to outperform regex in most situations.

Answer (score 2):

Like @Alexis Dufrenoy proposed, the query could be:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE find_in_set('sports', interests)>0 OR find_in_set('pub', interests)>0
```

More information in the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set).

Answer (score 2):

More work examples:

```
SELECT COUNT(email) as count FROM table1 t1 
JOIN (
      SELECT company_domains as emailext FROM table2 WHERE company = 'DELL'
     ) t2 
ON t1.email LIKE CONCAT('%', emailext) WHERE t1.event='PC Global Conference';
```

Task was count participants at an event(s) with filter if email extension equal to multiple company domains.