# mysql searching short words

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have a query which looks for a number of keywords which works fine using fulltext indexes but there is an issue with products like 'Adidas Adistar Salvation 3'

The 3 is actually important but the mysql fulltext index doesn't include it in the search.

What would be the best way to make sure a row contained "Adidas","Adistar" & "Salvation 3"

Normally the search would be:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE (title LIKE "%adidas%" AND title LIKE "%Adistar%" AND title LIKE "%Salvation%" AND title LIKE "%3%")
```

Many thanks
Brett

Comment: "What would be the best way to make sure a row contained "Adidas","Adistar" & "Salvation 3"". Isn't that: LIKE "%Salvation 3%" instead of LIKE "%Salvation%" AND title LIKE "%3%". Also adidas case does not match

Comment: cheers - what do you mean that the adidas case doesn't match? isn't mysql case insensitive?

Comment: Well LIKE isn't casesensitive (I think) so it doesn't matter but Adidas and %adidas% had different cases

Comment: `Adidas` has a capital letter on the data example but `adidas` is all lower cased on the search pattern. This sould be not an issue if you use a ci (case insensitive) charset.

Answer (score 0):

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172195/mysql-like-multiple-values), you could try using `REGEXP`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM products 
WHERE title REGEXP "adidas|Adistar|Salvation 3"
```

You could also try [find_in_set()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)