# SQL getting two 'TYPE'

Tags: mysql

I would like to get two of the same value when I Query my database.
I do not have amazing SQL knowledge so I wouldn't know where to start doing this so i'm asking for help from this friendly community.
To help me explain what I am looking for I will show you what I mean.

"SELECT * FROM $databasename WHERE **type='post' and type='friend_post'**  ORDER BY time desc"

(i put the area I am looking at in darker font)
This is what I am trying to do but it dosen't seem to work. Thanks in advance for any help I get, it will be much apreciated.

Comment: You need to use `OR` in order to get both.

Comment: As msfoster said, nothing will match AND.  A record can't have two values in it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL search multiple values in same field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16240041/sql-search-multiple-values-in-same-field)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you check if `type` is both value, use `IN` instead.

Which would looks like

```
SELECT * 
FROM $databasename 
WHERE type IN('post','friend_post')
ORDER BY time desc
```

Comment: Thankyou so much! That had me for hours :P

Comment: Awesome, thats even better! amazing. Thank you so much!