# How to find definitions of a morpheme in wordnet MySQL

Tags: mysql, wordnet

When I search for the definition for a word let's say 'surprise'. It gives me all the meanings.

```
SELECT words.lemma, synsets.definition FROM words INNER JOIN senses USING (wordid) INNER JOIN synsets USING (synsetid) where words.lemma = 'surprise'
```

[image]

This is the same as mentioned online on Princeton's website.

[image]

Now when I search for a morpheme of this word - 'surprising' all I am getting is just a single definition wheres wordnet shows four taking other three from the base form surprise.

[image]

[image]

**How do I get which definitions of the base word are used by the morphemes?**

Comment: You can add more *where* clause, and indicate the words that are most frequent in your first search. Refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16240041/sql-search-multiple-values-in-same-field) which OP aims to optimize his searching algorithm.

Comment: You probably need to do your own stemming.

Comment: @bishop even after doing stemming how would I find that only verb forms are used and not the noun.