# need to perform a database select functionality for each value in the array

Tags: javascript, php, sql

I need to perform a database select functionality for each value in the array. Parameter `theRequestApplicationName` contains an array like

`["fb","dropbox","twitter"]`

i need select functionality, in the below mentioned query it should be like application.name = each value of array. Please help me to solve this

```
ApplicationLogoutUrl = function (theRequestId, theRequestApplicationName, theRequestOrg, connection, res)
{
   theQuery = "select org_uses_app.app_logout_url 
                from  application, org_uses_app 
                where application.id=org_uses_app.application 
                and application.name = --";
}
```

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16240041/sql-search-multiple-values-in-same-field

Comment: First of all you should use a framework with ORM. Secondly, if you are not using ORM at least don't use the input directly in SQL and use place holders with prepared statements. Your life will be a lot easier!

Answer (score 0):

for multiple search value, you can use the sql query `IN` as in the answer here [SQL search multiple values in same field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16240041/sql-search-multiple-values-in-same-field)

Answer (score 0):

> Your sql query should be like this -

```
//$array variable is your array name like below
// $array = ["fb","dropbox","twitter"];

 theQuery = "select org_uses_app.app_logout_url from  application, org_uses_app 
             where application.id=org_uses_app.application and application.name IN 
             ('$array[0]','$array[1]','$array[2]')";
```

Comment: sorry i want to select app_logout_url for each value (). ie 
"select org_uses_app.app_logout_url from  application where application.name $array[0]
next
"select org_uses_app.app_logout_url from  application where application.name $array[1]
like this dynamically

Comment: Is you want to make 3 different queries with where condition ?

Comment: no i want each  array element in where clause.
need to get the logout url of $array[0]
next  logout url of $array[1]
for each array index i

Answer (score 0):

Basic structure of the query can be

```
    SELECT item FROM database.table WHERE firstCondition OR secondCondition
```

Assuming the database is named `applications`, has `apps` table with following attributes `id` and `name` with one record `{id: 'fb', name: 'facebook'}` the query in php will be

```
    SELECT app_logout_url 
    FROM applications.apps 
    WHERE id = fb  OR name = facebook;
```

Comment: i need to make it dynamic. ie for each value of array element. i want to each value of array element in the where clause dynamically