# linq query for searching lists

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List property of type string. I would like to search my database to make sure that the list matches the results. For example:

```
List<string>strings = new List<string>({"test1","test2","etc"});
```

I would now like to do a search in my database using linq to check if under certain condition that these strings exist.

```
_databaseContext.Names.Where(x=>x.name == strings && specialID == 1);
```

Comment: What is the problem or question?

Comment: @Amy there's a problem in his where clause although I don't know if that is his problem.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172195/mysql-like-multiple-values (also it is for MySQL) to see what kind of query you may need (OR'ed conditions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
_databaseContext.Names.Where(x => strings.Contains(x.name) && specialID == 1);
```

If your list of strings is unique, use can use `HashSet<>` instead of `List<>`. I think it will give you better performance.

```
HashSet<string> hs = new HashSet<string> { "test1", "test2", "etc" };

_databaseContext.Names.Where(x => hs.Contains(x.name) && specialID == 1);
```

**EDIT**: +1 to Alexei Levenkov for pointing out- `Exists` will cause problems, should use `Contains` instead. Also, verified the same query generated for `List` as well as `HashSet` so in case you want to query on server, is does not matter whether you use `List`or `HashSet`.

Generated query will be some thing like.

```
Select [name], [other columns]
From Names
Where [name] IN (N'test1', N'test2', N'etc')
```

However, assuming `specialID` is local variable, it will generate a dynamic query similar to above but also pass its value to SQL Server. This query is executed using `sp_executesql`.

Comment: +0: I'm not sure if this will not force query to be executed mostly on client due to function call in the predicate.