# retrieve checkbox values with uppercase and lowercase letters

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, sql

I have a search form where there are multiple checkboxes as inputs:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="search[]" value="pool">pool</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="search[]" value="pc">pc</input>
```

Now, based on the above check boxes, if I select both the values (`pool` and `pc`), everything starting both "pool" and "pc" has to be retrieved in all combinations--like `POol`,`POOl`,`pOOl`,`Pc`, etc. This needs to occur server-side in PHP.

How do I dynamically search from the database for all combinations? Can I somehow use [the answers to the question "Mysql Like multiple values"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172195/mysql-like-multiple-values)?

Comment: Can you share any SQL code you are using, and which columns you are search.

Comment: @BinaryAlchemist,I was going through some sql lessons and suddenly these doubts flashed into me.....So I do not have any code.sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL Code below will return results that match any or your search terms stored in `$_POST['search']`.   Since MySQL matches text in a case insensitive manner there is not additional step to match the different case of `$_POST['search']`.

```
<?php
  $sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE col IN ('%s')", implode("','",$_POST['search']) );
```

[sprintf](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

[implode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)