# How can I optimize an AND with multiple NOT LIKE statements inside of it?

Tags: mysql, performance

I can't really use an IN statement because the wildcards in my situation are very necessary. Any help is appreciated.

```
AND ((NOT (j.Note LIKE '%audit%'
            OR j.Note LIKE '%discrepancy%'
            OR j.Note LIKE '%returns%'
            OR j.Note LIKE '%shipment error%'
            OR j.Note LIKE '%inventory adjustment%'))
            OR j.Note IS NULL)
```

Comment: `REGEXP` maybe? Not sure it would actually be any better though.

Comment: Can you improve your data structure? Your query becomes much simpler if you have separate columns to track whether a given row is an audit, discrepancy, return, etc. Tinyint columns with values of 1 for true and 0 for false should suffice.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins This is probably the best answer, but I am still curious if there is another way if we assume I can't modify the data structure.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172195/mysql-like-multiple-values

Comment: @NagasimhaIyengar That's the same as my current query. The problem with it is that it doesn't perform very well.

Comment: @Uueerdo `REGEXP` prevents indexes from being used, and in my situation the index is the only thing keeping this query under a minute.

Comment: @JustinEmmons I am fairly sure using `LIKE` with a leading `%` prevents index use as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are stuck with looking at *all* rows.

- `LIKE '%...'` cannot use an index because of the leading wildcard
- `REGEXP` can do all the testing in one try, versus multiple `LIKEs`, so it might be faster
- `AND NOT (...)` does not help
- `OR` does not help
- `FULLTEXT` can't be very helpful because of the 'negative' testing.
- etc.

I recommend this:

```
AND j.Note IS NOT NULL
AND j.Note REGEXP 'audit|discrepancy|returns|shipment error|inventory adjustment'
```

If `Note` has lots of `NULLs`, then `INDEX(Note)` *may* help by avoiding the `NULLs`.

Here's another approach:  As you *insert* rows, categorize them as "audit" or ...  Then have another column (perhaps a `SET`) that flags which categories each Note belongs to.

If each Note belongs to only one category, then use ENUM and index it.  If not, testing the SET would be a little faster than LIKEs or REGEXP.

Comment: I would select this as the best answer, but in my example `j.Note` can be `NULL` and `AND j.Note NOT LIKE 'audit|discrepancy|returns|shipment error|inventory adjustment'` so maybe it would be:  
`AND j.Note NOT REGEXP 'audit|discrepancy|returns|shipment error|inventory adjustment'
OR j.Note IS NULL`

Comment: Be cautious of `a AND b OR c` -- That means `(a AND b) OR c`, _not_ `a AND (b OR c)`.