# Show publications according to the interests of the users

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to show publications according to the interests (in keywords) of the users.

**USERS TABLE**

```
id | username
5  | joelsilva
```

**PUBLICATIONS TABLE**

```
id | publication title
8  | The best car of the year!
```

**TABLE OF INTERESTS**

```
id | username | interest
8  | joelsilva | car
9  | joelsilva | year
```

It shows all the publications with the car title and year on the home page.

**I've tried this**:

```
$pubs = mysql_query(
    "SELECT * 
      FROM PUBLICATIONS 
      WHERE (interest LIKE '%".$interests."%')
      ORDER BY id desc"
) or die(mysql_error());
```

**It works**, **but** only with one type of interest in the table. If adding more than one interest shows nothing.

Comment: Please explain what you mean.  What algorithm do you want to use?

Comment: A lot will depend on how you populate $interests....  if you are just concatenating the keywords together you would get like %car year% so unless you have those words in that order with nothing between them then it will not work.....  If you concatenate a % between the keywords it might work better, or you may need to build up the query adding a OR condition for each of the interests.

Comment: I want to use php code with mysql_query

Comment: This is my code:
    $request_username_user_cookie= $requestusercookie["username"];
    $request_interesses_total = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM interesses WHERE user='$request_username_utilizador_cookie'");
    $request_interesses = mysql_fetch_assoc($request_interesses_total);
    $Interesses= $request_interesses["interesses"];
   $ pubs = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM PUBLICATIONS WHERE (interesse como '%". $ Interesses. "%') ORDER BY id desc") ou morrer (mysql_error ());

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172195/mysql-like-multiple-values similar question

Comment: Thankssss! <3 - It´s work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the publications and the interests on the title containing the interest and get the distinct rows of publication. Filter for the user.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       p.*
       FROM publications p
            INNER JOIN interests i
                       ON p.title LIKE concat('%', i.interest, '%')
       WHERE username = ?
       ORDER BY p.id DESC;
```

(BTW: Instead of the user's name, their ID should be in the interests table. And you should probably have a look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) to learn why you shouldn't use string concatenation when building queries but parameterized queries.)

Comment: I´m using this code, you can become $ in the right place ...?$request_username_user_cookie= $requestusercookie["username"]; $request_interesses_total = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM interesses WHERE user='$request_username_utilizador_cookie'"); $request_interesses = mysql_fetch_assoc($request_interesses_total); $Interesses= $request_interesses["interesses"]; $ pubs = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM PUBLICATIONS WHERE (interesse como '%". $ Interesses. "%') ORDER BY id desc") ou morrer (mysql_error ());