# How to find all employees that contain all character sequenences in their name?

Tags: jpa, micronaut, micronaut-data

I'm trying to write a Micronaut Data JPA finder that finds all `employees` that match to a list of strings.

Given the following employees (first name, last name)

- John Doe
- Jane Doe
- Peter Pan
- Silvio Wangler
- Franka Potente
- Frank Potter

Lets pretend a user queries the system with a query like *Silvio* then the result should be

- Employee: Silvio Wangler

If the query is *Frank* the result should be

- Employee: Franka Potente
- Employee: Frank Potter

And if the query is *frank pot* the result should as well (case insensitive like)

- Employee: Franka Potente
- Employee: Frank Potter

I managed to write a finder for a single string as listed below

```java
Page<Employee> findAllByLastNameIlikeOrFirstNameIlike(
      String lastName, String firstName, Pageable pageable);
```

For a query like  *frank pot* I would like to tokenize/split the string to a list ["frank", "pot"] and was wondering if I could implement something like

```java
Page<Employee> findAllByLastNameIlikeOrFirstNameIlike(
      List<String> lastName, List<String> firstName, Pageable pageable);
```

or even better use the Criteria API of JPA. How would you implementent such a search finder? Can you point me the direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing i always think of, is how to do it in plain SQL.
Found that one [MySQL Like multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172195/mysql-like-multiple-values)

So i suggest the best way is using the criteria API and build your own dynamic query. 
Have a look at the first example https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-data/latest/guide/#repositories which gives you everything you need from micronaut.

i use the ciriteria api also if i have some kind of dynamic querys like 'give me everything from start to end but if start is not specified just give me everything before end ... '