# Display related products by matching the product title to any tags of the current article

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, tags, related-posts

How do I display products in a custom post type single page by matching the queried product title to any tags of the current article?

Below is my code which seems to output some random product names, but it should only be returning one product (at the moment) where product title is also a tag in the current post... with me?

```
            <?php 

            // Query products related to current article

            $current_article_tags = get_the_tags();

            $related_products = new WP_Query(array(
              'post_type'=> 'product',
              'title'    => $current_article_tags
            ));


            while(  $related_products->have_posts()){
                $related_products->the_post(); 

                // Get products number
                $related_product_count = $related_products->post_count;

                //echo '<pre>'; print_r($related_products->posts); echo '</pre>';
                echo $related_products->post->post_title; 

                ?>

            <?php
            }
            wp_reset_postdata();
            ?>
```

Comment: It may be worth posting this on wordpress.stackexchange.com. You cannot pass `title` to `WP_Query`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to query by an array of values:

[MySQL Like multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172195/mysql-like-multiple-values)

```
WHERE interests LIKE '%sports%' OR interests LIKE '%pub%'
```

In your case, we can probably make that structure quite nicely using [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and maybe [`strtolower`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) (`get_the_tags` returns an array of terms, we need them to look like the above)

```
$current_article_tags = get_the_tags();
$tags_for_query = array_map(function($term){
  // Post title 1 ==> '%post title 1%'
  return "'%" . strtolower($term->name) . "%'";
}, $current_article_tags)
```

Now we should have an array like this

```
[
  '%post title 1%',
  '%post title 2%'
]
```

We need to join them into a string, or [`implode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) them in php language

```
$sql = "WHERE post_title LIKE " . implode(" OR post_title LIKE ", $tags_for_query);
```

`$sql` should now output something like...

```
WHERE post_title LIKE '%post title 1%' OR post_title LIKE  '%post title 2%'
```

I hope this gets you started.